# Mount windows partition

Tags: ubuntu

Are there any potential problems with mounting a windows 10 data partition with Ubuntu? Could it corrupt the files? I plan to use Linux tools to verify folders on different drives are identical down to the bit.

Comment: No. You'll just need NTFS drivers support.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would be only reading from that mount, so if mounting with the read-only option, then nothing could get corrupted for sure.

Even if writing something, NTFS has some built-in recoverability. Possibly only some abrupt power loss during a write operation might render some corrupt file, but not corrupt the NTFS file system. FAT is something else though.

I personally mount a shared folder of my Windows 10 laptop's disk (NTFS) onto an Ubuntu 18 VM that runs on that same Windows' Hyper-V, using read & write permissions. Have not had any problem yet whatsoever, after a couple of years using it. The specific command I use:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //<windos-laptop-name>/<shared-folder> /opt/mywinshare -o username=<mydomainusername>,domain=<domain>,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777
```

(Notice that such command can ask for two passwords: your password for sudo itself, then the domain password for the specified user in the specified domain, who must be a user with permissions to access that Windows shared folder, btw.)

Comment: I think OP means change the files more so than actually corrupt them. I suspect that they are nervous of something like changing line endings or something similar. As you say, in read only they are all set but file system protections wouldn't help if they edited a file with both OSes.